# How to prevent acronyms from expanding in special areas

Tags: acronyms, acro

I have a few acronyms that go into the chapter titles and table of contents.

I do not want these to expand in the title and table of contents. For example:

```
\chapter{My nice chapter title got ruined \ac{LOL}}
```

so obviously, this "LOL" will be expanded, and the title reads:

> My nice chapter title got ruined Laughing Out Loud (LOL)

I know I could omit `\ac` but then I wanted it to be clickable in the PDF so people can click on it if necessary

Is there a way? like `\acnoexpand{LOL}`?

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the `acro` package since you added it as a tag to your question. In the future, **please specify these details in your question and provide an MWE.** If you read the [documentation](https://us.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/acro/acro-manual.pdf), you'll see that the package provides the `\acs` command, which prints only the short form of the acronym. Also, if you use the acronym at least once before you use it in `\chapter`, the acronym won't expand in the `\chapter` anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!